# Wcf Restful Service gives Method Not allowed or Bad Request

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-rest

my service has been defined:

```
[ServiceContract(ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.None)]
[XmlSerializerFormat]
public interface IMSMService
{

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false)]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "GetProducts", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    ProductsResponse GetProducts(ProductsRequest request);

}
```

and the method header takes the form:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class MSMService : IMSMService
{.....
```

I run the service and then in the client app I make a service reference to the wcf process. In my client Test project I have the following test.

```
 [Test]
    public void CallWCFRestful()
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ProductsRequest));

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

        xmlSerializer.Serialize(stream,_productsRequest);

        string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray(), 0, (int)stream.Length);
       string link = "http://localhost/WcfService/GetProducts";
       var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(link));

        request.ContentType = "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8";
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;
        request.KeepAlive = true;

        using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {

            var writer = new StreamWriter(requestStream);

            writer.Write(data);

            writer.Flush();

        }

        using (HttpWebResponse resp = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {

            using (var responseStream = resp.GetResponseStream())
            {

                var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

                var result = reader.ReadToEnd();

            }

        }
    }
```

In Code when I have the service running, it errors when trying to set 'resp' with a bad request error. If I do ctrl+click on http://localhost/WcfService then this shows the service running. If I include the method as per my line of code, then I receive Method not allowed (I'd expect this because I'm not passing the object). What have I done wrong.

Comment: Is the link valid.  I mean the service endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

As this is a WCF REST service, the content type cannot be SOAP. It needs to be application/xml. Try changing the content type and testing again. That could be the reason =, or at least one of the reasons.

Change as follows:

```
request.ContentType = "application/xml; charset=utf-8";
```